# Laravel 5: How to get posts by specific categories and display in tabs

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm building a news site. I want to get 6 latest posts by 3 specific categories, lets say id 2, 3, 4, and display them in 3 tabs on homepage.
Each tab is divided in 2 column, col-6. one col-6 display the latest record, the other display a list of another 5 records after the latest one.

Here's my controller, I get 6 latest records from database

> $post_tabs = Post::with('categories')->latest()->limit(6)->get();

this I get 3 categories that have id 2, 3, 4

> $category_tabs = Category::with('posts')->whereIn('id', [2, 3, 4])->get();

In blade view, I managed to display that 3 category tabs, like so

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarToggler1">
<ul class="nav nav-sm navbar-nav mr-md-auto mr-lg-0 mt-2 mt-lg-0 align-self-end" role="tablist">
    @foreach($category_tabs as $tab_category)
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link bg-color-tech active" id="nav-outdoor-tab-{{$tab_category->id}}" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-outdoor-{{$tab_category->id}}" role="tab" aria-selected="true">
                {{$tab_category->title}}
            </a>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul></div>
```

Now I don't know how to display posts of those categories by tabs, this is what i 've got so far, which only display 6 latest post and I don't know how to make tabs work either

```
@foreach($post_tabs as $key => $post_tab)
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-outdoor-{{-- {{$tab_category->id}} --}}" role="tabpanel">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            @if ($loop->first)
            <article>
                <div class="entry-image mb-3">
                    <a href="{{route('post.show',[$post_tab->slug])}}"><img src="{{asset($post_tab->thumbnail)}}" alt="{{$post_tab->title}}"></a>
                    @foreach($post_tab->categories as $category)
                    <div class="entry-categories"><a href="#" class="bg-tech">{{$category->title}}</a></div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
                <div class="entry-title">
                    <h3><a target="_blank" href="{{route('post.show',[$post_tab->slug])}}">{{$post_tab->title}}</a></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="entry-content clearfix">
                    <p>{{$post_tab->description}}</p>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            @foreach($post_tabs as $key => $post_tab)
            @if($key > 0) 
            <article>
                <div class="entry-image">
                    <a href="#"><img src="{{asset($post_tab->thumbnail)}}" alt=""></a>
                </div>
                <div class="entry-c">
                    <div class="entry-title">
                        <h4><a href="#">{{$post_tab->title}}</a></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
            @endif
            @endforeach
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to fetch category and post separately. You can fetch both using eager loading. For that you can define extra relationship in Category model like this

Category Model

```
public function latestPosts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App/Post')->latest()->take(6);
}

public function beforeLatestPosts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App/Post')->latest()->slice(6)->take(5);
}
```

Fetch in controller

```
$category_tabs = Category::with('latestPosts', 'beforeLatestPosts')->whereIn('id', [2, 3, 4])->get();
```

**In view**

Print Tab header

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarToggler1">
    <ul class="nav nav-sm navbar-nav mr-md-auto mr-lg-0 mt-2 mt-lg-0 align-self-end" role="tablist">
        @foreach($category_tabs as $tab_category)
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link bg-color-tech active" id="nav-outdoor-tab-{{$tab_category->id}}" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-outdoor-{{$tab_category->id}}" role="tab" aria-selected="true">
                    {{$tab_category->title}}
                </a>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

Print Tab Content

```
@foreach($category_tabs as $tab_category)
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-outdoor-{{$tab_category->id}}" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                      @foreach($tab_category->latestPosts as $latestPost)
                        <article>
                            <div class="entry-image mb-3">
                                <a href="{{route('post.show',[$latestPost->slug])}}"><img src="{{asset($latestPost->thumbnail)}}" alt="{{$latestPost->title}}"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="entry-title">
                                <h3><a target="_blank" href="{{route('post.show',[$latestPost->slug])}}">{{$latestPost->title}}</a></h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="entry-content clearfix">
                                <p>{{$latestPost->description}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                      @endforeach
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    @foreach($tab_category->beforeLatestPosts as $beforeLatestPost)
                        <article>
                            <div class="entry-image">
                                <a href="#"><img src="{{asset($beforeLatestPost->thumbnail)}}" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="entry-c">
                                <div class="entry-title">
                                    <h4><a href="#">{{$beforeLatestPost->title}}</a></h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```